# 1-d interpolation of cell array with time series data

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, interpolation

I have a 15174x21 cell array with various measures over a time series (as per below) in each column that includes NaN values. Would I be best suited using a For Loop for each column to interpolate out the NaN values but preserve the dimensions of the array?

```
93.36   93.36   9.3218  23.03   14.0967 22.0596 6.66088 24.3851
93.4    93.4    9.31331 23.0291 14.0115 21.9569 NaN     NaN
93.44   93.44   9.32774 23.0266 14.1254 22.1864 6.6727  24.4036
93.48   93.48   9.32612 23.0336 14.1612 22.1168 6.40944 24.3949
93.52   93.52   9.32374 23.0362 14.0691 22.1711 NaN     NaN
93.56   93.56   9.31864 23.0342 14.1201 22.1799 6.15716 24.2267
```

Thanks

Comment: If this is an entirely numeric matrix, why would you want to represent this as a cell array?  Why don't you change this to a numeric matrix and use `interp1` applied to the columns simultaneously wherever a `NaN` is encountered?  A `for` loop is definitely not required here.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for your reply here. I've tried this using a numeric array but I cannot preserve the dimensions, instead it is a single row vector that is produced.

Comment: Did you try using `cell2mat`?  I don't believe your statement I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to interpolate based on the values before and after a NaN-value; you can find the index of each NaN-value, and change it based on the values proceeding and superceeding that value. See example below:

```
[r, c] = find(isnan(cell2mat(TimedEditNumbersWS3)));
for i = 1:length(r)
    if r(i) == 1
        k = 1;
        while isnan(TimedEditNumbersWS3{r(i)+k,c(i)})
            k = k + 1;
        end
        TimedEditNumbersWS3(r(i),c(i)) = TimedEditNumbersWS3(r(i)+k,c(i));
    else
    TimedEditNumbersWS3(r(i),c(i)) = {(TimedEditNumbersWS3{r(i)-1,c(i)} + TimedEditNumbersWS3{r(i)+1,c(i)}) / 2};
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply here. I tried a variation of your code but received the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

Comment: Is there anywere I can get a hold on your exact cell array? Or could you perhaps explain it's format thouroughly. Is every element in it's own cell or each column in a cell?

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Here's a link to the data. http://www.filedropper.com/po1r2

Comment: If it's any consolation, I've made it work use the `resample`function. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, ok. I just solved it (perhaps you would like to handle NaNs in the first row differently though). I'll post my solution anyway, perhaps it could be of some help. You'll find the code in my original answer (I just edited it). If you like it, please upvote ;P Have a great weekend, Matt!

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts here! Apparently I need to earn more reputation to upvote your answer publicly. I will do my best to do so but thank you again from me personally.

Comment: I understand. I'm in the same position with the reputation points :P Anyway, I'm glad to be of help :)